# moving file in folders based on word from title

Tags: file, pdf, directory

I have several thousand pdf, epub, mobi, djvu files in a folder.
I would like to use a script to move these files to certain folders in the following way:
for example I can put a parameter in the script - the word that is in the title of the file - say witch - and the script will move all the files that have the word witch in the title into a folder to called Magic.

i dont have coding knowlege